# How do I update the additional fields from 1 table based on the data from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 temp tables `#tempbackfilltable` and `#temptablelive`. The backfill table has more entries than the live table. After cross referencing both tables and getting the additional entries using this code:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #tempbackfilltable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM #temptablelive b
                  WHERE a.DataDate = b.DataDate
                    AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode)
  AND DataDate >= '2021-08-04';
```

I want to update one of the columns (DBTimestamp) in `#tempbackfilltable` using existing data in `#temptablelive`. The existing data I would like to update is the min(DBTimestamp) for the day in `#temptablelive`. I tried running something like this:

```sql
Update a 
set a.DBTimestamp = b.DBTimestamp
FROM #tempbackfilltableShaun a
RIGHT JOIN #tempbackfilltable b
ON  a.DataDate = b.DataDate AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode
Where NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM #tempbackfilltable b WHERE a.DataDate = b.DataDate AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode)
and a.DataDate >= '2021-08-04'
```

However, this gives me 0 rows. I also tried

```
Update #tempbackfilltableShaun 
set #tempbackfilltableShaun.DBTimestamp = b.DBTimestamp
FROM #tempbackfilltableShaun a WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM #tempbackfilltable b WHERE a.DataDate = b.DataDate AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode)
and DataDate >= '2021-08-04';
```

but this gave me an error saying b.DBTimestamp cannot be bound.

For illustration:
#temptablelive

```
DataDate   | StockCode | DBTimeStamp 
2021-12-10   688396      2021-12-10 03:22:04.000
2021-12-10   688399      2021-12-10 03:22:04.000
2021-12-10   688568      2021-12-10 03:22:04.000
2021-12-10   688981      2021-12-10 03:22:04.000
2021-12-13   688577      2021-12-13 03:10:23.000
```

#tempbackfilltable

```
DataDate   | StockCode | DBTimeStamp 
2021-12-10   688396      2021-12-10 00:00:00.000
2021-12-10   688399      2021-12-10 00:00:00.000
2021-12-10   688568      2021-12-10 00:00:00.000
2021-12-10   688981      2021-12-10 00:00:00.000
2021-12-13   688396      2021-12-13 00:00:00.000
2021-12-13   688505      2021-12-13 00:00:00.000
2021-12-13   688599      2021-12-13 00:00:00.000
```

As you can see, even though the date is correct in DBTimeStamp, the time is off so I would like to update the time based on the #temptablelive.

Desired output on #tempbackfilltable

```
DataDate   | StockCode | DBTimeStamp 
2021-12-10   688396      2021-12-10 03:22:04.000
2021-12-10   688399      2021-12-10 03:22:04.000
2021-12-10   688568      2021-12-10 03:22:04.000
2021-12-10   688981      2021-12-10 03:22:04.000
2021-12-13   688396      2021-12-13 03:10:23.000
2021-12-13   688505      2021-12-13 03:10:23.000
2021-12-13   688599      2021-12-13 03:10:23.000
```

Comment: maybe the  DBTimeStamp  column format  in #temptablelive table is date not datetime

Comment: Get into the habit of using *good* aliases. Aliases like `a` is for `Customer` and `b` is for `Account`, or `t1` is for `Purchase` and `t2` is for `Transaction` aren't helpful for you or others that want to read your code. Use meaningful and *consistent* aliases for your objects. I suggest a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: You must use an `inner join` to get only matching pairs for `update`. Alternatively you must use `insert` to add missing rows.

Comment: I'm not looking for matching pairs, I want to alter the data with the additional rows.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the desired result to clarify the problem.

Comment: why use right join?

Comment: `2021-12-13   688599` has no matching row in the #temptablelive table. Where does  2021-12-13 03:10:23.000 comes from ?

Comment: yup cause the entries with DataDate 2021-12-13 in #tempbackfilltable are the extra entries that I want to change the DBTimestamp of based on the existing entry 688577 in #temptablelive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two updates for matching and non-matching rows respectivley. Alternativevly you can use MERGE specifying that unmatched souce gets max DBTimeStamp from the respective set of rows from the source

```
merge #tempbackfilltable b
using #temptablelive a
   on a.DataDate = b.DataDate AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode and a.DataDate >= '2021-08-04'
when matched then
   update set DBTimeStamp = a.DBTimeStamp
when not matched by source then
   update set DBTimeStamp = (select max(DBTimeStamp) 
                             from #temptablelive c
                             where b.DataDate = c.DataDate)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

First test your query and check old and new value like this:

```
SELECT a.DBTimestamp, b.DBTimestamp
FROM #tempbackfilltable a
RIGHT JOIN #temptablelive b
ON  a.DataDate = b.DataDate AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode
Where NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM #temptablelive b WHERE a.DataDate = b.DataDate AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode)
and a.DataDate >= '2021-08-04'
```

After you resolve the problem (b.DBTimestamp must not be null), then change the query to update statment.

```
Update a 
set a.DBTimestamp = b.DBTimestamp
FROM #tempbackfilltable a
RIGHT JOIN #temptablelive b
ON  a.DataDate = b.DataDate AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode
Where NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM #temptablelive b WHERE a.DataDate = b.DataDate AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode)
and a.DataDate >= '2021-08-04'
```

Comment: This removes the error but I think my query logic is wrong as the output is 0 rows. I have edited the question with another query I tried

Answer (score 0):

check this query

```
UPDATE #tempbackfilltable a
SET a.DBTimestamp = b.DBTimestamp
JOIN (select  min(DBTimestamp)  DBTimestamp , DataDate,StockCode from #temptablelive
group by DataDate,StockCode )  b
ON  a.DataDate = b.DataDate AND a.StockCode = b.StockCode
Where NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM #temptablelive c WHERE a.DataDate = c.DataDate AND a.StockCode = c.StockCode)
and a.DataDate >= '2021-08-04'
```